# error: [Hilt] Found unimplemented abstract methods, [provideOpenWeatherApi()], in an abstract module, com.example.weathersforecast.di.ApiModule

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am developing an android app  using jetpack compose and dagger hilt but when I run project I am getting the following error

```
ApiModule.java:8: error: [Hilt]
public abstract interface ApiModule {
                ^
  Found unimplemented abstract methods, [provideOpenWeatherApi()], in an abstract module, com.example.weathersforecast.di.ApiModule. Did you forget to add a Dagger binding annotation (e.g. @Binds)?
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
```

below AppModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface ApiModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOpenWeatherApi(): WeatherApi {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(WeatherApi::class.java)

    }
}
```

I want to know where I am making mistake I have tried all stackoverflow answers it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed AppModule to from interface to object thats fixed my problem